# Sharing branches and labels between 2 VoB Clearcase

Tags: clearcase

How do i share branches and labels created in type explorer between two Vobs in ClearCase 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to link those two vobs with a common admin vob, in order to define **[global types](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_proj.doc/c_bntr_impldev_gblty.htm)**.

> The Rational® ClearCase® global type facility makes it easy for you to ensure that the branch, label, attribute, hyperlink, and element types they need are present in all VOBs your project use.

See "[VOB datatypes and administrative VOB hierarchies](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.books.cc_admin.doc/type-admin.htm)".

[image: vob hierarchy]

> In general, all operations on a global type or a local copy of a global type apply to the global type and all its local copies.
>
> Most cleartool type-creation commands (see Predefined and user-defined type objects) support a `-global` option, which creates a global type object. The following command creates a global label type in VOB \admin:

```
cleartool mklbtype -c "final label for REL6" -global REL6@\admin 
Created label type "REL6".
```