# Create label with clearcase

Tags: label, clearcase

I would like to create a label from anywhere by explicitly specifying the **VOB** name. Unfortunately no matter how I specify my **VOB** I always get this error:

```
$ cleartool mklbtype -global -nc MyVOBName:MY_LABEL_NAME
cleartool: Error: Invalid name: "MyVOBName:MY_LABEL_NAME".
cleartool: Error: Unable to create label type "MyVOBName:MY_LABEL_NAME".
```

Or even:

```
$ cleartool mklbtype -global -nc -vob MyVOBName MY_LABEL_NAME
cleartool: Error: Unrecognized option "-vob"
Usage: mklbtype [-replace] [-global [-acquire] | -ordinary] [-pbranch] [-shared]
                [-c comment | -cfile pname | -cq | -cqe | -nc]
                label-type-selector ...
```

The only thing that works is going directly in the correct **VOB** with `cd L:\MyVOBnane`.

Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should

```
cd /path/to/your/vob
cleartool mklbtype -global -nc MY_LABEL_NAME
```

I don't see a `-vob option` in [`cleartool mklbtype`](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v8r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mklbtype.htm) (and anyway it should be with `-vob \MyVOBName`, not `-vob MyVOBName`: you must use the vob tag `\MyVobName`).

You can use:

```
cleartool mklbtype -global -nc lbtype:MyLabel@\MyVobName
```

That last one can be executed from anywhere.

Creating the lbtype globally is useful to share it amongst Vob: see "[Sharing branches and labels between 2 VoB Clearcase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10650364/6309)".

---

Note that it creates a label *type*, it doesn't label.
For that, you need to go into a view and type (using [`cleartool mklabel`](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v8r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc%2Ftopics%2Fct_mklabel.htm)):

```
cleartool mklabel -rec -nc MyLabel .
```

See another example at "[What is the difference between clearcase and vss in label a release?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1277549/6309)".

Comment: Why I don't have the `-vob` option? Is it a new option to CC?

Comment: @coin there is no '`-vob`' option. I have edited the answer accordingly and added a link to the documentation.

Comment: Unfortunately this not work I get: `cleartool: Error: Unable to determine VOB for pathname "MyVobName".` when I use `ct mklbtype -nc lbtype:MyLabel@\MyVobName`

Comment: @coin do you see `\MyVobName` when you type `cleartool lsvob`?

Comment: Yes I do see it but I can also read `* \MyVobName \\server\clearcase\vost64\MyVobName.vbs public (replicated)`

Comment: @coin then it will work, as it follows the `[lbtype:]type-name[@vob-selector]` convention described in the doc.